# Clarification on Web8 Installation steps regarding "MTSUser"?

Tags: web8, installation, sdl-tridion

While we are installing SDL Web8 one of the Step says
"Create and configure an MTSUser account on the domain controller machine of your Windows domain."

Do I need to create MTS User with exactly same name "MTSUser" or Can i use "DeVMTSUser"?

If I forgot "MTSUser" password or Admin left without sharing the password, If I reset the password what are the components will be impacted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The username can be anything you want, MTSUser was the default user name for Microsoft Transaction Server (MTS) in the past, and we never bothered changing the default name.

Security-conscious people will tell you that you *should* rename it to something else.

This account is used to connect to the search indexers (configurable in the MMC plug-in) and to run any COM+ component (if you use legacy code in your system). So, in short - your search will stop working if you change the password.

Comment: Do we need to create MTSuser in Local or Can I create user in Active Directory and use it. When I tried MTSUser created in Active Directory it says account not found.

Comment: It has to work with AD, as this is the recommended setup for CM clusters

Comment: I guess "account not found" is what would happen if the account you're running under now does not have permission to read the AD tree (for instance, a local machine administrator)